# Unable to install Mono 2.6 on CentOS

Tags: centos, gcc, mono, glibc

I have an application that breaks on mono 2.10, so I'm trying to install an older mono instead.

I found an [RPM](ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/epel/6/x86_64/mono-core-2.4.3.1-4.el6.i686.rpm) and tried to install it, but it won't install (I believe) because the glibc and gcc versions that are on CentOS 6.3 are too high. (it actually says it lacks the dependencies for GLIBC_2.7 and GCC_3.3.1 even though I have versions 2.12 and 4.4 installed as part of CentOS 6.3, so I can only assume it's a problem because they're too high)

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3):

Compile your desired version of Mono from source instead of relying on a pre-built pacakge.

Comment: I get 1/3rd of the way down the [list](http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_From_Git) and then it says "Package glib-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path". Same with gthread-2.0

Comment: This does seem to help, but I had to install `gtk2-devel` first (`yum install gtk2-devel`)

Comment: Try following this guide - http://wiki.phonicuk.com/Installing-Mono-in-CentOS-5-x.ashx - I wrote it originally for CentOS 5 but it works for CentOS 6 and just about any version of Mono from 2.6 onwards.

Comment: thank you I'll take a look I'd love to tell you how I got on but sadly I won't be able to because I won't be part of this forum any more

Answer (score 0):

Download the source rpm and then `rpmbuild --rebuild mono-XX.XX.src.rpm` and it should dump finished rpms with your libraries in `/usr/src/redhat/RPMS/`.

Comment: thanks for the help aaron but please read up